# Downloading File from Firebase Storage not working

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-storage

In my Angular app I am trying to retrieve a file saved on firebase storage.

To this end I wrote the following code:

```
    var storage = firebase.storage();
    var fileRef = storage.ref(`${this.idOfCurrentUser}/personalData.card`);

    var blob = null;

    console.log("THIS LINE DOES GET PRINTED");
    fileRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {

        console.log("THIS LINE NEVER GETS PRINTED");
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.onload = function(event) {
            blob = xhr.response;  
        };
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.send();

    }).then(function() {
        //some more code
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

This code follows the documentation for firebase (https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files) ... but it does not work.

Specifically, the program gets stalled at the following line:

```
fileRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
```

There is no error message in the console. But the wheel turns forever and the whole app becomes unusable.

Does anybody know a working way to retrieve a file from Firebase Storage?

---

UPDATE:

Following a suggestion from Joseph Webber, I changed the first lines of the code to the following:

```
    var storage = firebase.storage();
    var id = this.idOfCurrentUser;
    var fileRef = storage.ref(`${id}/personalData.card`);
```

However, the problem stays exactly the same.

---

UPDATE2:

Following another suggestion from Joseph Webber, I also tried the following:

```
var fileRef = storage.child(`${id}/personalData.card`);
```

However, this gives the following error message:

```
"Property 'child' does not exist on type 'Storage'"
```

[image]

---

UPDATE3:

also tried this:

```
var fileRef = storage.ref(this.idOfCurrentUser + "/personalData.card");
```

... didn't make a difference either

---

P.S.: The storage rules are the following:

[image]

Comment: What do your storage rules look like?

Comment: see P.S. to my post

Comment: Does it work if you don't use a template literal? `storage.ref(this.idOfCurrentUser + '/personalData.card')` Are you sure the path is correct (`id` vs `uid`) and that the file exists?

Comment: the path is correct but your comment gave me an idea ... the id is of type "firstname.lastname@email.com_182283832" ... maybe firebase cannot handle folders named like this?

Comment: It should, since none of those characters are restricted from directory names. Just to be sure, try making a test directory and file in firestore without special characters in their names and hardcoding the path in a new firestore ref. If that doesn't work, I suggest checking your firebase environment variable to make sure the paths are correct.

Comment: I changed the id (and the folder name) to a string containing only letters and numbers ... it still doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178264/discussion-between-joseph-webber-and-steady-progress).

Comment: Hi, Could you share a link to fiddle or a public link to this specific part of your program, to let us examine the code much easier and provide you much more accurate results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it now. The problem was related to an infinite loop in another function that was executed in parallel.

Comment: Maybe you can ask for a refund for your bounty :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `this.` from your template literal.

```
var fileRef = storage.ref(`${idOfCurrentUser}/personalData.card`);
```

**Edit**

Try changing `storage.ref` to `storage.child`.

```
var fileRef = storage.child(`${id}/personalData.card`);
```

Comment: thank you for your comment ... it doesn't make a difference though, unfortunately (see UPDATE to my post)

Comment: thank you for your suggestion - but it still doesn't work ... see UPDATE2